# Attaching a listener to a cell and getting "out of memory" exception

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where I click a button. This button creates two forumla strings (which are C# excel addin/UDFs) and then pastes them into two cells. The first creates some data and stores it in the cache and the second function uses the data inserted into the Excel cache. The problem has been that the second function has executed too early, before the data was inserted.

I therefore wrote a function to act a listener and when the value of the first cell is edited:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Sheets("1").Range("A1") Then           'The error is here
        Sheets("1").Cells(5, 1).Calculate
    End If
End Sub
```

When I click on the button which creates the formulae/function string I get:

Run-time error'7': Out of memory

I do not understand why this is? the line of the error is:

```
If Target = Sheets("1").Range("A1") Then
```

**EDIT It's getting caused by the fact when I click on the button I clear the contents of the whole of sheet X. Is there any wayaround this?**

Comment: Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the If Condition and then add `Application.EnableEvents = True` after the `End If` and try again?

Comment: Is Sheet1 really named "1" (text you see on the tab)? I don't believe that's what's causing your issue, but still good to check.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that Excel starts a recalculation by calculating formulas in a Last-in-First-Out sequence: so it would be sensible to make your button code calculate your first formula to create the cache (you could use Range.calculate or any other appropriate Calculate method) before entering your second formula.